# Java multithreading concept

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a question on multithreading.

Suppose I want to perform two actions simultneously like I want to add a friend record to a file and also display the friend record using concurrent threads at the same time.

I created a single thread which started and the display was taken care by it and in the main method which started the thread I performed the action of saving the record to file.

Do both of these processes occur simultaneously.

This is part of my code.

```
Runnable2 r2 = new Runnable2(L) ;
Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
t2.start();

F.addElement(L);
oos1.writeObject(F);
```

Comment: You started a thread, so the code in the Runnble2's run() method executes in a separate thread, yes. Please respect the Java naming conventions and choose descriptive names rather than F, L, r2, t2 and Runnable2.

Comment: They may occur simultaneously. It really depends on your hardware and other factors if they actually do.

Comment: You can benchmark serial and threaded codes and compare timings if java already doesnt separate independed codes to different threads automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as simultaneosuly. One will happen before the other, but, if you do not use explicit synchronization mechanisms, you cannot know which will be executed first (it depends on the OS, on hardware, on the JVM). It is very possible that if you run the program 100 times, 99 times event 1 will run before event 2, and the last time it happens the other way around, and you get one of those bugs that are so difficult to reproduce.

You really should not count on the order and you should use synchronization mechanisms when using multi-threading.

Comment: Why wouldn't there be such thing as simultaneously? Most computers have multiple cores these days. So that multiple things *can* execute simultaneously.

Comment: @JBNizet  Academic literature only uses the word "simultaneous" to describe a relationship between discrete _events_ (e.g., memory accesses).  When they talk about procedure/function/method calls (i.e., sequences of events), those are either "overlapped" or not.  Some events in an SMP computer can happen simultaneously, but the ones that are interesting never do:  E.g., The hardware will never allow two different processors to update the same main memory location at the same time.  So, in the strict language of computer science, there is no _useful_ meaning of the word "simultaneously."

Comment: Well, this is not academic literature. This is a plain English comment on whether instructions of two threads are executed simultaneously or not. And they are in a multi-code machine.